# how can i put the title tooltip output beside the input?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip

i tried to make the title output like this
[image]

title output's beside the input.
but the result of my code is allways at top of the input.

and this's my code

insertpage.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Home Page </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'> <!-- Css Buatan -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"> <!-- Css BootStrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">      
</head>

<body>

<?php 

$tanggal    = date("Y-m-d");

echo"
<br>
<center>
<div id='boxedit'>
<center> Insert New Page </center><br>
<form id='form1' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='simpanpage.php' method='post'>

<table border=1 class='table'>
        <tr>
            <td> Foto </td>  <td> <input type='file' name='fotoh'> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Judul </td>  <td> <input title='Masukan Judul Disini' type=text name=judul id=judul maxlength='50' size='50' required placeholder='Masukan Judul'> <small>*</small> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Deskripsi </td>  <td> <textarea title='Masukan Deskripsi Disini' class='inserttext' required rows='9' cols='80' id=deskripsi  name='deskripsi' > </textarea> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Isi </td>  <td> <textarea title='Masukan Isi Disini' class='inserttext' required rows='9' cols='80' id=isi name='isi'> </textarea>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Label </td> <td> <input title='Masukan Label Disini' required  type=text id=label name=label  placeholder='Masukan Label'><input type=hidden name=tgl_dibuat id=tgl_dibuat value=".$tanggal."> <small>*</small> </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <br>
    <button id='btn'>Save</button>
<br> <div class='hasil'> </div>
</form> 
</div>
</center>
<br>
<br>
";

?>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>

$('document').ready(function(){

    $(function() {
        var tooltips = $( "[title]" ).tooltip({
            position:{
                my: "left top",
                at: "right+5 top-5"
            }
        });

    });
})



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

meybe something's wrong with my jquery script or something like that 
 please i need help here, i tired to fix this one.
im really thanks for your attention.

edited code :
index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Home Page </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'> <!-- Css Buatan -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"> <!-- Css BootStrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

</head>

<body>

<!-- Memulai Tampilan Header -->

<div class="bs-component">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">ARK-LYOD&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Pages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="manage.php">Manage Pages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="insertpage.php">Tambah Page Baru</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/mr.araku.lyod">About Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php 

$tanggal    = date("Y-m-d");


echo"
<br>
<center>
<div id='boxedit'>
<center> Insert New Page </center><br>
<form id='form1' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='simpanpage.php' method='post'>

<table border=1 class='table'>
        <tr>
            <td> Foto </td>  <td> <input type='file' name='fotoh'> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Judul </td>  <td> <input title='Masukan Judul Disini' type=text name=judul id=judul maxlength='50' size='50' required placeholder='Masukan Judul'> <small>*</small> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Deskripsi </td>  <td> <textarea title='Masukan Deskripsi Disini' class='inserttext' required rows='9' cols='80' id=deskripsi  name='deskripsi' > </textarea> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Isi </td>  <td> <textarea title='Masukan Isi Disini' class='inserttext' required rows='9' cols='80' id=isi name='isi'> </textarea>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Label </td> <td> <input title='Masukan Label Disini' required  type=text id=label name=label  placeholder='Masukan Label'><input type=hidden name=tgl_dibuat id=tgl_dibuat value=".$tanggal."> <small>*</small> </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <br>
    <input type=submit id='btn' value='Save'>
<br> <div class='hasil'> </div>
</form> 
</div>
</center>
<br>
<br>
";

?>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>

$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $('#form1').attr('action'),
            type: "POST",
            data : new FormData($('#form1')[0]),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success:function(){
                alert("Berhasil Insert");
                $('input').val("");
                $('textarea').val("");
            }
        });
    })

    $(function() {
        var tooltips = $( "[title]" ).tooltip({
            position:{
                my: "left top",
                at: "right+5 top-5"
            }
        });

    });
})



</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user1415571 i do my apologize about that, my question is how can i put the title tooltip output beside the input?
that's my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your link to the jQuery UI css files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Note the missing `http:`

Fix that and it will start working.

This is how it looks on my computer (without your own css):

[image: This is how it looks (without your own css)]

Also note that if there is not mush space available on the left side, the tooltip will move to a location where space is available. So keep the browser window maximised to test this.

Comment: not worked my friend..
i've tried but the result is allways at the top of input...
i want the title output's beside the input

Comment: It works when I try it. See this http://jsfiddle.net/krizskp/nojsL9ee/
Even works as a normal file on my localhost.
Could you show me the updates you made, please?

Comment: hmmm i used maxthon and mozila and that's not work out for sure ...
did u use my code?
i just bit confused here :(

Comment: Yes, I used your code exactly as it is in the question above. Just added the `http:` to the css link.

Comment: i've been add HTTP:
but that's nothing happen in my page...
wait i'll show you my updated code

Comment: Your updated code works fine. I tested on Chrome and Safari browsers.

Comment: really?
how about on mozila and maxthon browser

Comment: Seems like your browser is not getting the css from the CDN. You can try and download the css file and save it with the website files and link it locally. Just like your own css files.

Comment: Using it locally, you won't have the http anymore. You'd link it using the local file structure. I haven't tested on Mozilla yet. You could try Chrome or something.

Comment: why the css and positioning is not compatible for maxthon and mozila firefox, what should i add?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't done web development for some time now and haven't used Mozilla. So I'm not sure what changes have been made to Mozilla. But lately, I've seen many issues with Mozilla (which may not be bugs at all).